# Generating ImportError: `load_model` requires h5py in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras

I am running the following github code for Age and Gender Detection on jupyter notebook (anaconda navigator)
https://github.com/kaushikjadhav01/Deep-Surveillance-Monitor-Facial-Emotion-Age-Gender-Recognition-System

I am using latest version of Anaconda Navigator and created a new environment with python=3.7.
Installed the required libraries and packages, but when loading the model it gives error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading an `.H5` file, you may need a supporting library installed in your system.

You can resolve this error by using the below code:

```
!pip install h5py
```